# Why this function work returns the string even though the pointer points at the null terminator? (pointers)

Tags: c, pointers

I am learning the basics of C, and I would like to know why this function works.

```
char *strCpy(char *dest, char *orig) {
    while (*orig != '\0') {
        *dest = *orig;
        dest++;
        orig++;
   }
    *dest = '\0';
    return dest;
}

int main(void) {
    char string1[30 + 1] = "Hello world";
    char string2[30 + 1];
    strCpy(string2, string1);

    printf("%s\n", string2);

    return 0;
}
```

At the end of the function `dest` points to the null terminator, so why does the function still return the string?

I was expecting the function to return an empty string as the pointer points at the null terminator by the end of the function

Comment: Your program doesn't use the return value, you might as well not return anything at all (`void`) and get the same result.

Comment: You're only ever copying the pointer of `string2`, you're not using the return value.

Answer (score 3):

C function arguments are passed by value. When you pass `string2` to `strCpy` it decays to a pointer to the first element, and that pointer value is *copied*. The array `string2` in `main` is modified by `strCpy`, but the pointer that `string2` decays to when passed to a function like `strCpy` will not change.

Now, the return value of `strCpy` will always be an empty string. If you printed that, you would see an empty line output.

If you with to return a pointer to the destination string, you can copy that pointer before manipulating it, and return that copy.

```
char *strCpy(char *dest, char *orig){
  char *dest_begin = dest;
  while(*orig != '\0'){
    *dest = *orig;
    dest++;
    orig++;
  }
  *dest = '\0';
  return dest_begin;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand what happened. The function I crated was only modifying string2, the function was returning an empty line.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in the line

```
strCpy(string2, string1);
```

you aren't assigning the return value of strCpy to any variable.
This isn't necessary, but you can declare the function as returning void, if you are only using the function for its side-effects.

Second: The function receives the address of string2 as first arg and copies that address into dest. Via dest you are actually changing the elements to which string2 is pointing. When the function returns, dest is basically irrelevant. It was only useful in order to change the values of string2.
(Note that you are constantly using the indirection operator * - which indicates that you change the elements at the address to which dest is pointing)

Comment: If the return type is modified, I would suggest `size_t` and taking the opportunity to return the number of characters copied. It would save the user of this function from duplicating effort later if they wish to know the length of the string.

Answer (score 0):

string2 is pointing to the same address when you call the function because you donot get the returned address from strCpy function.

```
char *strCpy(char *dest, char *orig){ // (B0, A0)
  while(*orig != '\0'){
    *dest = *orig; // set value at A0 to B0
    dest++; // moving to next address B1 ....
    orig++; // Moving to next address A1 ....
  } // do the same until get `\0`; it seems that dest is B11, orig is A11
  *dest = '\0'; //set the last of dest = '\0'; or the value at B11 = '\0'
  return dest; // return B11
}

int main(void){
  // length of string1 is 11; so string1[11] will be '\0'
  char string1[30 + 1] = "Hello world"; // string1 address is at : A0 .... A30
  char string2[30 + 1]; // string2 address is at: B0 ... B30
  strCpy(string2, string1); // donot return any pointer
  char *dest = strCpy(string2, string1);// if you use like this, you can get the value at address B11
  printf("%s\n", string2); // string2 address is not changed, it is pointing to B0

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't use the return value of the function so what's returned there doesn't matter in this case. If looking at the real standard lib function `strcpy` it returns a pointer to the beginning of the destination string. This too is optional to use, mainly it can be used for situations like `printf("%s", strcpy(s2, s1));`.

But then notably, if we were to implement `strcpy` ourselves and mimic the behavior of the function, then your code wouldn't do. Since it is based in incrementing one of the function parameter variables, we would first have to store that one away. A fixed function might look like:

```c
char *strCpy (char *dst, char *src){
  char* start = dst; // save this for later
  while(*src != '\0'){
    *dst = *src;
    dst++;
    src++;
  }
  *dst = '\0';
  return start; // return a pointer to the first character
}
```

Furthermore, the pointer version isn't all that readable so we could consider writing a version based on a for loop instead:

```
char *strCpy2 (char* dst, char* src){
  char* start = dst;
  
  for(size_t i=0; src[i] != '\0'; i++)
  {
    dst[i] = src[i];
  }
  *dst = '\0';

  return start;
}
```

Performance-wise this is probably about the same, but `for` loops with an incrementing index are often more readable than pointer arithmetic.

Also please observe *const correctness*: if we pass a pointer to a function but do not modify what that pointer points at, it should be declared read-only:

```
char *strCpy2 (char* dst, const char* src)
```

Const correctness prevents accidental bugs, creates self-documenting code and sometimes also helps with increasing the performance.

Answer (score -1):

If you actually wanted to print the return value, this method will work

```
int main(void){

  char string1[30 + 1] = "Hello world";
  char string2[30 + 1];
  char *retstr = strCpy(string2, string1);

  printf("%s\n", retstr); // will print empty string

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code without explanation is not a good answer. This post does not answer OP’s question of why their code prints the string.

Comment: I would normally agree, but the way the OP said "so why does the function still return the string" and "I was expecting the function to return an empty string" this code was the quickest way to show that the function DOES NOT return the string.